# how can i access my directory

Tags: c#

I want to access the path for my directory, but I can not. I put a breakpoint in my code:

```
string directoryPath = args[0];
```

And when i clicked on the `args[0];`, it showed me this image:

```
-       args    {string[3]} string[]
        [0] "C:\\Users\\soft\\Documents\\Visual"    string
        [1] "Studio"    string
        [2] "2010\\Projects\\erereerer\\erereerer\\bin\\Debug\\MAXee\\" string
        directoryPath   null    string
        filesList   null    string[]
        filesListTmp    null    string[]
        opList  null    erereerer.IFileOperation[]
```

I have been trying to access my directory but I have been failing. I tried so many times but when I run my code its saying directory does not exist while the directory is in fact there..

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      string directoryPath = args[0];
      string[] filesList, filesListTmp;
      IFileOperation[] opList = { new FileProcNameAfter10(),
                                  new FileProcEnc(),
                                  new FileProcByExt("jpeg"),
                                  new FileProcByExt("jpg"),
                                  new FileProcByExt("doc"),
                                  new FileProcByExt("pdf"),
                                  new FileProcByExt("djvu")
   };

   if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
   {
      filesList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
      while (true)
      {
         Thread.Sleep(500);
         filesListTmp = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);

         foreach (var elem in Enumerable.Except<string>(filesListTmp, filesList))
         {
            Console.WriteLine(elem);

            foreach (var op in opList)
            {
               if (op.Accept(elem)) op.Process(elem);
            }
         }
            filesList = filesListTmp;
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
       }
    }

    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("There is no such directory.");
       Console.ReadKey();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking your program?

Comment: Pass your argument between double quotes

Comment: @cdhowie im just compiling but its returning a message There is no such directory when the directory actually it does  exist

Comment: I think you are passing an invalid path as an argument. I have tested your code, it works fine with my local folder. Could you post the command line argument you are passing? That would help us to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> [0] "C:\Users\soft\Documents\Visual"    string
>           [1] "Studio"    string
>           [2] "2010\Projects\erereerer\erereerer\bin\Debug\MAXee\" string

It tells me that you are passing the arguments without quotes.

Call you program this way:

```
MyApp.exe "C:\Users\soft\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\erereerer\erereerer\bin\Debug\MAXee\"
```

Or just do what Blachshma said:

```
directoryPath = String.Join(" ", args);
```

Comment: I would argue against joining the string, since the person invoking the program should be passing the path as one argument in the first place.  It ultimately depends on whether one wants to document this particular (mis)feature and have to support it in future versions.

Comment: @cdhowie Sure, I am just showing all the possible methods to get it done. The OP must see what is best for him/she.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the directory in quotes:

```
MyProgram.exe "C:\Users\soft\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\erereerer\erereerer\bin\Debug\MAXee\"
```

or **[Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)** the `args` in code:

```
directoryPath = String.Join(" ", args);
```

Comment: when i pass it in double quotes im getting this again [0] = "C:\\Users\\soft\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\erereerer\\erereerer\\bin\\Debug\\MAXee\""

Comment: But that is what you wanted, isn't it? The full directory? Did the second solution help?

Comment: but im getting a message that the directory does not exisit i thought when this is taken care of the directory will show

Comment: Both solutions say directory doesn't exist? If so, try opening VS as Administrator (Right click VS icon and choose "run as administrator") does it work with above solutions now?

Comment: yes both solutions are saying the same thing let me try as an administrator

Comment: If as an Administrator it still happens please go with Windows Explorer to the final directory (into MAXee) and copy the full path into here so we can make sure you don't have a typo somewhere along the line...

Comment: not working here is the path i copied from explorer...C:\Users\soft\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\erereerer\erereerer\bin\Debug\MAXee

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25561/discussion-between-blachshma-and-thanks)